# Fastest way to get the count of records per day between two dates

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table in SQL Server, I want to calculate the count of records in per day for example, you imagine we have two dates "2017/12/01" to "2018/01/12"

```
Date          New York     LA       Boston     Chicago    Cleveland    
===================================================================
2017/12/01        10      800      820         245          90
2017/12/02       200       30      120         112         356
2017/12/03       500       44       58          34         321
2017/12/04       120      540       98          67         651
.......
```

Also city has a code that column name is `CityCode` for example

```
new york = 1 , LA = 2 , Boston = 3 , Chicago = 4 , Cleveland = 5
```

but there is a notice in date column. In fact, my date column is based on string format not the date format. I've written some code, but it has a exception with converting string date to DateTime format.

This code just return results of new York city. Do you think it should repeat this code 5 times for other cities?

```
public class OrderDateSummary
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
}

var startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate);
var endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate);
var newYork = db.tbl_bar
               .Where(t => startDate <= DateTime.ParseExact(t.date_rec_slash, "yyyy/MM/dd", null) && DateTime.ParseExact(t.date_rec_slash, "yyyy/MM/dd", null) <= endDate && t.CityCode == 1)
               .GroupBy(t => t.date_rec_slash, (date, values) =>
                             new OrderDateSummary()
                                 {
                                     Date = date,
                                     Total = values.Count(),
                                 })
               .OrderBy(summary => summary.Date)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: If it looks like a date, talks like a date, smells like a date - ***why*** aren't you **storing** it as a `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` data type?!?!?!? You should ***always*** use the ***most appropriate*** data type available - no exceptions - and you should **not** store dates as strings!

Comment: Is it because your date format is Shamsi?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani No,I'm working Gregorian date,but In database my date is stored based on string "2017/12/01" what is your idea for solving it?

Comment: @marc_s,I agree you but how to can solve it right now? I don't change my table values because it has a thousands records based on string date not datetime.

Comment: You have given an example in linq, so I assume you would like the answer in linq, but just checking that you definitely do not want to use SQL? as it would be very simple to do. This comment is not intended to start a discussion about pros and cons of sql and orm :)

Comment: @Felbus, So,please tell me SQL way Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT date::DATE, count(citycode) as total,
CASE
  WHEN citycode = 1 THEN 'New York'
  WHEN citycode = 2 THEN 'LA'
  WHEN citycode = 3 THEN 'Boston'
  WHEN citycode = 4 THEN 'Chicago'
  WHEN citycode = 5 THEN 'Cleveland'
END
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE date::DATE between '2017/12/01' AND '2017/12/31'
GROUP BY date::DATE, citycode
ORDER BY date desc;
```

For SQL Server you may have to use

`Cast(date as datetime)`
instead of 
`date::DATE`.

To use as a stored procedure, do this:

`USE YOUR_DATABASE_NAME
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE ANY_PROCEDURE_NAME
AS
  now_put_sql_here
GO`

Run that and it will create a stored procedure named "ANY_PROCEDURE_NAME" in "YOUR_DATABASE_NAME"